# FileSystemWatcher Invalid data Exception error

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, filesystemwatcher

[image]
I want to refresh my datagridview if there are changes in a particular xml file. I got a FileSystemWatcher to look for any changes in the file and call the datagirdview function to reload the xml data.

When i tried, i'm getting `Invalid data Exception error` Somebody please tell what is the mistake am i doing here??

```
  public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

                watcher.Path = @"C:\test";
                watcher.Changed +=  fileSystemWatcher1_Changed;
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                //watches only Person.xml
                watcher.Filter = "Person.xml";

                //watches all files with a .xml extension
                watcher.Filter = "*.xml";

            }

            private const string filePath = @"C:\test\Person.xml";
            private void LoadDatagrid()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(filePath, new XmlReaderSettings()))
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //Here is the problem
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                } 
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoadDatagrid();
            }

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                LoadDatagrid();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `FileSystemWatcher` runs on a distinct thread, not the UI thread. On winforms apps only the UI thread - the main thread of the program - can interact with visual constrols. If you need to interact with visual controls from another thread - like this case - you must call `Invoke` on the target control.

```
 // this event will be fired from the thread where FileSystemWatcher is running.
 private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
 {
      // Call Invoke on the current form, so the LoadDataGrid method
      // will be executed on the main UI thread.
      this.Invoke(new Action(()=> LoadDatagrid()));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The FileSystemWatcher is running in a seperate thread and not in the UI thread. To maintain thread safety, .NET prevents you from updating the UI from the non-UI thread (i.e. the one that created the Form components).

To resolve the issue easily, call the MethodInvoker method of the target Form from your fileSystemWatcher1_Changed event. See [MethodInvoker Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) for more details on how to do this. There are other options on how to do this, incl. setting up a synchronized (i.e. thread-safe) object for holding the results/flag of any event, but this requires no changes to the Form code (i.e. in case of games, one could just poll the synchronized object in the main game loop etc).

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Invoke an anonymous method on the thread of the form.
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
        this.LoadDataGrid();
    });
}
```

Edit: Corrected previous answer which had a problem within the delegate, the LoadDataGrid was missing this. and it would not resolve as such.